# Ensure an element has a proper offset from another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not exactly sure how to better phrase the title above so if you can think of a more clear and concise title feel free to re-phrase it.

---

I am creating a generic tool-tip with HTML, CSS, and Javascript (no jQuery, Angular, etc.). I've made it to a point where everything looks pretty clean, until I resize the window and scroll down. Now, from my understanding, mobile devices do not have an `onmouseover` or `onmouseout` event and therefore I do not need to account for this; however, if I take into account the smaller screens of some laptops (I've seen 10 inch screens) then this could be an issue.

When I hover over one of the elements (they are all `a` elements in this example), the tool-tip appears as it should, however when I resize as I described above, the `onmouseout` event is firing because the mouse is technically over the tool-tip, not the element anymore. I thought that offsetting from the position of the element by its height plus five pixels that I would be safe from that issue, but it seems that the position isn't the position I'm expecting.

---

I am currently using `getBoundingClientRect()` to calculate the positions but I believe this is based on the view port position while I think I'm needing based on the position in the page instead that way as the page moves so does where the tool tip is. I've included my code below and you can test it out and see what I'm talking about.

```js
var tooltip = document.getElementById("globalTooltip");
function showTooltip(sender) {
 var senderBounds = sender.getBoundingClientRect();
 var top = senderBounds.y + senderBounds.height + 5;
 tooltip.dataset.owner = sender;
 
 tooltip.innerHTML = sender.dataset.tooltip;
 tooltip.classList.add(sender.dataset.tooltiptype);
 
 if (top + tooltip.getBoundingClientRect().height + 5 > window.innerHeight)
  top = senderBounds.y - tooltip.getBoundingClientRect().height - 5;
 
 tooltip.style.top = top + "px";
 tooltip.style.left = (senderBounds.x + 5) + "px";
 tooltip.classList.add("active-tooltip");
}
function hideTooltip(sender) {
 tooltip.style.left = "-250px";
 tooltip.classList.remove("error");
 tooltip.classList.remove("warning");
 tooltip.classList.remove("success");
 tooltip.classList.remove("neutral");
 tooltip.classList.remove("active-tooltip");
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.disabled-link {
 color: #777;
 cursor: default;
}
li {
 padding: 5px;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 cursor: default;
 border-radius: 25px;
 color: #333;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 max-width: 30vw;
}
.neutral { background-color: #ddd; }
.success { background-color: #7c7; }
.warning { background-color: #fc3; }
.error   { background-color: #f55; }
.active-tooltip { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a class="disabled-link"
     data-tooltip="This link is available in another location."
     data-tooltiptype="warning"
     onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">
     Hover Over This Disabled Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Active Link</a></li>
  <li>
   <a class="disabled-link"
     data-tooltip="Something great is coming soon!"
     data-tooltiptype="success"
     onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">
     Hover for more details...</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Active Link</a></li>
  <li>
   <a class="disabled-link"
     data-tooltip="This area is currently under maintenance."
     data-tooltiptype="error"
     onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">
     Another Disabled Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Active Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Active Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Active Link</a></li>
  <li>
   <a class="disabled-link"
     data-tooltip="This is an example of what happens when the text supplied to the tooltip is rather verbose instead of the enjoyable concise messages that are typically used to relay information instead. No one likes to read a novel in a tooltip, but hey, it's not my decision, it just has to be accounted for due to an excessive and old page."
     data-tooltiptype="neutral"
     onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">
     Really Verbose Message</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<i id="globalTooltip" data-owner="none" class="tooltip"></i>
```

---

How can I ensure the tool-tip is always offset from the element instead of flying in over it?